# Как работает режим incognito в google chrome?

Tags: linux, windows, google-chrome, браузер

Стало интересно,

Я читала, где-то пишут, что хром сохраняет изображения, css, js другие файлы во временном кэше во во время браузинга в incognito во временном хранилище и их можно восстановить. Где-то пишут что

> What happens when you browse privately
> Chrome won't save your browsing history, cookies and site data, or information entered in forms.
> Files you download and bookmarks you create will be kept.
> Your activity isn’t hidden from websites you visit, your employer or school, or your internet service provider.

Но на некоторых сайтах пишут что можно восстановить информацию из этого кэша. Подскажите пожалуйста, какая информация правдива? Сохраняет ли браузер файлы для сайтов на диск и можно ли их восстановить потом?

Comment: Во-первых, не вижу противоречия. Во-вторых, проще взять и проверить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а как проверить?

Comment: Указать папку в качестве профиля и отследить, что за файлы в ней создаются и меняются и время работы.

Comment: @Qwerity, ну кстати я попробовала этот способ и у меня получился такой результат. Я сравнила запуск youtube на чистой дирректории Cache в инкогнито и в обычном mode, и получилось что инкогнито не создает файлы кэша. Точнее создает какие-то (по 1 штуке) но в непонятные-рандомные  моменты времени, но по количеству файлов сохраняемых в кэше эти режимы несоизмеримы